# Relacionar e comparar MySQL e VB6

Tags: mysql, visual-basic-6

Me passaram um sistema de uma empresa para atualização, possuem 3 tabelas MySQL 'vendaesc, venda, venda_forma_pagamento'. Pelo que entendi a tabela vendaesc serve para armazenar os itens da venda.

Preciso criar um relatório que me traga os dados do produto vendido, quantidade vendida, valor unitário, valor total da venda, forma de pagamento, parcelas e o problema vem aí, com frequencia em uma única venda inserem inúmeros produtos, mas, existe uma única forma de pagamento para a venda.
A informação da forma de pagamento é salva na tabela Venda.

A estrutura das tabelas:
Venda

```
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Cod` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Data` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Hora` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Desconto` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`TotalS` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
`TotalC` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
`Cod_Cliente` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Nome_Cliente` varchar(150) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Mes` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Ano` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`forma_pagamento` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`forma_pagamento_detalhe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`forma_pagamento_detalhe_nome` varchar(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`forma_pagamento_parcelas` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

Vendaesc

```
`Cod` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Venda` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`CodTipo` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Tipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ObsTipo` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`CodProd` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Prod` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`referencia` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ValUniProd` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`UniProd` varchar(5) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`QuantidadeProd` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`ValorProd` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Maquina` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Cod_Cliente` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Cliente` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Data` date DEFAULT NULL,
`Mes` varchar(45) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Ano` varchar(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Cod_vendedor` varchar(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`Nome_Vendedor` varchar(155) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (`Cod`)
```

Forma Pagamento

```
`cod` varchar(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
`descricao` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
```

Sql que tentei, 20% dos registros retornaram com dados errados em relação ao igual ou diferente

```
SQL = "SELECT *,
IF(venda.cod = vendaesc.Venda and venda.forma_pagamento > 1,'IGUAL','DIFERENTE') AS resultado_agrupa,
venda.TotalS AS total_venda_agrupa,
venda_forma_pagamento.descricao AS nome_forma_pagamento,
vendaesc.QUANTIDADEprod as qtd, 
(vendaesc.QUANTIDADEprod * vendaesc.ValUniProd) As total_soma

FROM vendaesc,venda,venda_forma_pagamento

where vendaesc.data='" & DateRat & "' AND
venda.cod = vendaesc.venda AND venda.forma_pagamento =
venda_forma_pagamento.cod  order by venda.cod"
```

Programação é VB6 :(

SQL:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a61f/1/0)

Comment: Você poderia preparar um exemplo de dados das três tabelas (não precisa ser muitos, algo que represente duas vendas por exemplo) e mostrar como seria o resultado desejado baseado nos dados que usar?! Facilitaria bastante a ajuda a você! Se puder fazer ainda melhor, crie um [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) com esse exemplo

Comment: Opa, obrigado por responder, o SQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a61f/1/0, o importante é o campo 'resultado_agrupa', retornar o valor correto, se for de uma mesma venda trazer o 'IGUAL' se não for trazer 'DIFERENTE', Vlw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lendo a sua pergunta e principalmente esse comentário:

> Opa, a ideia seria, gerar um relatório listando todos os itens de
>   vendaesc, como podem existir diversos itens em vendaesc para uma
>   venda, preciso que o relatório me informe que estes determinados itens
>   fazem parte da mesma venda, mostrando para o usuario caso seja da
>   mesma venda a palavra IGUAL, caso não, DIFERENTE

E diria que você está tentando fazer uma coisa errada, no seu `SELECT` você tenta colocar um `IF` ele vai comparar o valor da coluna 1 com a coluna 2 da mesma linha. No seu caso ele retorna diferente somente quando a forma de pagamento é maior que um (`venda.forma_pagamento > 1`). Da uma conferida que você vai ver que é por isso. Digo isso porque, se você faz um `JOIN` em `venda` e `vendaesc` pelo `cod` igual a `venda` (`AND venda.cod = vendaesc.venda`) e no `SELECT` você coloca `IF(venda.cod = vendaesc.Venda` então esse `IF` sempre será verdadeiro, porque se fosse falso ele não apareceria, porque o `WHERE` está obrigando a vir somente os que forem verdadeiros. Entendeu?

Com o SQL abaixo você pode ver a coluna `cod` com a coluna `venda` sempre iguais, é o mesmo `WHERE` do seu, mas com o `SELECT` alterado para ficar mais fácil de ver o resultado. Repara nas duas primeiras colunas. [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a61f/27)

```
SELECT venda.cod, vendaesc.venda, venda.forma_pagamento, vendaesc.codprod
  FROM vendaesc,
       venda,
       venda_forma_pagamento 
 where vendaesc.data='2015-11-12' 
   AND venda.cod = vendaesc.venda 
   AND venda.forma_pagamento = venda_forma_pagamento.cod  
 order by venda.cod

Cod Venda   forma_pagamento CodProd
000001  000001  1   00002
000002  000002  1   00002
000003  000003  1   00001
000004  000004  4   00001
000004  000004  4   00058
000004  000004  4   00067
000005  000005  1   00001
000005  000005  1   00002
```

Para reforçar vamos incluir o seu `IF` no `SELECT`, mas somente a primeira parte: [FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a61f/28)

```
SELECT IF(venda.cod = vendaesc.Venda,'IGUAL','DIFERENTE'),
        venda.cod, vendaesc.venda, venda.forma_pagamento, vendaesc.codprod
  FROM vendaesc,
       venda,
       venda_forma_pagamento 
 where vendaesc.data='2015-11-12' 
   AND venda.cod = vendaesc.venda 
   AND venda.forma_pagamento = venda_forma_pagamento.cod  
 order by venda.cod

IF(venda.cod = vendaesc.Venda,'IGUAL','DIFERENTE')  Cod Venda   forma_pagamento CodProd
IGUAL   000001  000001  1   00002
IGUAL   000002  000002  1   00002
IGUAL   000003  000003  1   00001
IGUAL   000004  000004  4   00067
IGUAL   000004  000004  4   00001
IGUAL   000004  000004  4   00058
IGUAL   000005  000005  1   00002
IGUAL   000005  000005  1   00001
```

Não preciso dizer que se você colocar a segunda parte do `IF` no `SELECT` todos os registros que tem forma de pagamento 1 vão vir com o resultado `DIFERENTE` no `IF`. Concorda?

O que eu sugiro no seu caso é, acreditando que você está usando cristal report, é fazer o seguinte SQL: *(O site está dizendo que eu preciso de 10 pontos de reputação para publicar mais de 2 links, não estou entendo o porque disso, por isso não vou colocar o fiddle desse SLQ, mas funciona no seu fiddle mesmo, desculpa por isso)*

```
SELECT vendaesc.*, venda.forma_pagamento
  FROM vendaesc,
       venda,
       venda_forma_pagamento 
 where vendaesc.data='2015-11-12' 
   AND venda.cod = vendaesc.venda 
   AND venda.forma_pagamento = venda_forma_pagamento.cod  
 order by venda.cod
```

Onde retorna todas as colunas que você precisa com o `WHERE` atendendo os filtros e no relatório você crie um agrupamento com o código da venda, com isso todos os itens vendidos organizados por vendas.

A coisa mais importante nessa resposta é você entender o seu `IF` no `SELECT`, ele não compara duas linhas diferentes no resulta, é um `IF` para cada linha.

PS: muda o `vendaesc.*` para uma lista com todas as colunas, seria uma boa pratica não usar o `*`

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que entendi o que deseja, gostaria de exibir todos os registros (um em cada linha) conforme a quantidade de produtos vendidos exibindo as informações completas das vendas.

caso sim, tente esta consulta:

```
SELECT * FROM venda v
LEFT JOIN vendaesc vesc ON v.Cod = vesc.venda
LEFT JOIN venda_forma_pagamento vfp ON vfp.cod = v.forma_pagamento
LEFT JOIN (SELECT Venda, SUM(CAST(REPLACE(ValorProd, ",", ".") AS DECIMAL(10,2))) as TOTALVALORPRDUTO FROM vendaesc GROUP BY Venda) as total ON total.Venda = v.Cod
```

Gostaria de salientar que não é uma boa prática utilizar VARCHAR para armazenar valores monetários, evite também o FLOAT pode ser perigoso. o recomendado é DECIMAL(10,2) por exemplo.

** Tive que adicionar um POG para converter o valorprod para decimal e substituir vírgula por ponto, pois no schema está como varchar.

Comment: Opa @Hoppy, obrigado por responder, no sql que enviei já traz todos os resultados que preciso, o único problema, de fato o que preciso, é verificar isso `IF(venda.cod = vendaesc.Venda and venda.forma_pagamento > 1,'IGUAL','DIFERENTE') AS resultado_agrupa` que não funciona bem, ou seja, é verificar se o Cod da venda é igual ao item Venda na tabela vendaesc, se for igual me trazer 'IGUAL' e diferente trazer 'DIFERENTE'

Comment: vou re-fazer aqui e edito a consulta.

Comment: Bom, primeiramente não entendi porque colocou venda.cod = vendaesc.Venda dentro do if, isso já foi relacionado no where vendaesc.data='" & DateRat & "' AND venda.cod = vendaesc.venda AND venda.forma_pagamento = venda_forma_pagamento.cod  order by venda.cod"..  a única coisa que esse IF está fazendo é caso a forma de pagamento seja maior que 1 retorne IGUAL caso contrário DIFERENTE, seria possível escrever as regras de negócio que você quer aplicar nesse campo para que eu possa reformular a resposta?

Comment: Opa, a ideia seria, gerar um relatório listando todos os itens de vendaesc, como podem existir diversos itens em vendaesc para uma venda, preciso que o relatório me informe que estes determinados itens fazem parte da mesma venda, mostrando para o usuario caso seja da mesma venda a palavra IGUAL, caso não, DIFERENTE